# How should I migrate my core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

My core data store in the previous version to my app is different to the current one in the following ways:

- Attributes missing
- New attributes
- Attributes which need changing
- New entities
- New relationships
- Attributes which need moving between entities

How should I go about migrating my data? What I had in mind before looking into this was that I could just write code that could take the data from the previous model and put it in place in the new model.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) will cover these issues in some detail.